# How to push data that contains specific column?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a NodeJS script that reads this huge

and I need to write new file that contains only rows of data that have valid numeric profit values and then order the data based on profit value, and

Comment: Shouldn't `results.profit` be `data.profit`? `results` is the array, not the current row of the CSV.

Comment: But since the field heading is `Profit (in millions)`, it should be `if (data['Profit (in millions)'])`

Comment: Why do you need two result arrays? If you just need the total number of lines, just increment a counter, you don't have to save the contents.

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the `mapHeaders` option to convert the column headings to lowercase, and just use the first word (so we discard "(in millions)").

Then if the `profit` column exists, I parse it to a `float`. Then we can later use that in `sort()` to get the top 20 rows by profit.

Instead of saving all the rows in `results`, I just increment a variable containing a line counter.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
let lines = 0;
const validResults = [];
const inputFile = "./data.csv";
fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
  .pipe(csv({
    mapHeaders: h => h.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase(),
  }))
  .on("data", (data) => {
    try {
      if (data.profit) {
        data.profit = parseFloat(data.profit);
        validResults.push(data);
      }
      lines++;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log('# of Rows of data is', lines);
    fs.writeFile('data2.json', JSON.stringify(validResults.sort((a, b) => b.profit - a.profit).slice(0, 20)), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("File created")
    })
  });
```

Comment: btw h.split is not a function

Comment: it should be. `h` is a string, and strings have a `split()` method.